# Can't run elastic beanstalk app locally using eb local run command

Tags: node.js, docker, express, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I followed the Elastic Beanstalk tutorial here

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_nodejs_express.html

And the app works perfectly fine when I deploy to EB; however, when I run `eb local run` it first complained about docker not being installed and needing version 1.6.0. I used homebrew to install the latest version, which is 4.16.2! I also `boot2docker` as it had suggested.

So, now I run the command `eb local run` and it complains with the following error

`ERROR: NotSupportedError - You can use "eb local" only with preconfigured, generic and multicontainer Docker platforms.`

Based on what I've gathered from other posts about similar issues, it may have to do with the `default_platform` in my `.elasticbeanstalk/config.yml` file, but that may just be a red-herring. The AWS documentation feels like it's very outdated.

Output of `eb local run --debug`

```
2023-02-02 18:53:52,934 (DEBUG) cement.core.foundation : laying cement for the 'eb' application
2023-02-02 18:53:52,934 (DEBUG) cement.core.hook : defining hook 'pre_setup'
2023-02-02 18:53:52,934 (DEBUG) cement.core.hook : defining hook 'post_setup'
2023-02-02 18:53:52,935 (DEBUG) cement.core.hook : defining hook 'pre_run'
2023-02-02 18:53:52,935 (DEBUG) cement.core.hook : defining hook 'post_run'
2023-02-02 18:53:52,935 (DEBUG) cement.core.hook : defining hook 'pre_argument_parsing'
2023-02-02 18:53:52,935 (DEBUG) cement.core.hook : defining hook 'post_argument_parsing'
2023-02-02 18:53:52,935 (DEBUG) cement.core.hook : defining hook 'pre_close'
2023-02-02 18:53:52,935 (DEBUG) cement.core.hook : defining hook 'post_close'
2023-02-02 18:53:52,935 (DEBUG) cement.core.hook : defining hook 'signal'
2023-02-02 18:53:52,935 (DEBUG) cement.core.hook : defining hook 'pre_render'
2023-02-02 18:53:52,935 (DEBUG) cement.core.hook : defining hook 'post_render'
2023-02-02 18:53:52,935 (DEBUG) cement.core.hook : registering hook 'add_handler_override_options' from cement.core.foundation into hooks['post_setup']
2023-02-02 18:53:52,935 (DEBUG) cement.core.hook : registering hook 'handler_override' from cement.core.foundation into hooks['post_argument_parsing']
2023-02-02 18:53:52,935 (DEBUG) cement.core.handler : defining handler type 'extension' (IExtension)
2023-02-02 18:53:52,935 (DEBUG) cement.core.handler : defining handler type 'log' (ILog)
2023-02-02 18:53:52,935 (DEBUG) cement.core.handler : defining handler type 'config' (IConfig)
2023-02-02 18:53:52,935 (DEBUG) cement.core.handler : defining handler type 'mail' (IMail)
2023-02-02 18:53:52,935 (DEBUG) cement.core.handler : defining handler type 'plugin' (IPlugin)
2023-02-02 18:53:52,935 (DEBUG) cement.core.handler : defining handler type 'output' (IOutput)
2023-02-02 18:53:52,935 (DEBUG) cement.core.handler : defining handler type 'argument' (IArgument)
2023-02-02 18:53:52,935 (DEBUG) cement.core.handler : defining handler type 'controller' (IController)
2023-02-02 18:53:52,935 (DEBUG) cement.core.handler : defining handler type 'cache' (ICache)
2023-02-02 18:53:52,935 (DEBUG) cement.core.handler : registering handler '<class 'cement.core.extension.CementExtensionHandler'>' into handlers['extension']['cement']
2023-02-02 18:53:52,944 (DEBUG) cement.ext.ext_plugin : plugin config dir /etc/eb/plugins.d does not exist.
2023-02-02 18:53:52,944 (DEBUG) cement.ext.ext_plugin : plugin config dir /Users/username/.eb/plugins.d does not exist.
2023-02-02 18:53:52,947 (DEBUG) ebcli.core.hooks : -- EBCLI Version: 3.20.3
2023-02-02 18:53:52,947 (DEBUG) ebcli.core.hooks : -- Python Version: 3.10.9 (main, Feb  2 2023, 17:23:54) [Clang 13.1.6 (clang-1316.0.21.2.5)]
2023-02-02 18:53:52,947 (DEBUG) ebcli.core.fileoperations : Project root found at: /Users/username/Documents/GitHub/server
2023-02-02 18:53:52,949 (DEBUG) ebcli.objects.sourcecontrol : Getting current branch name by performing `git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD`
2023-02-02 18:53:52,968 (DEBUG) ebcli.objects.sourcecontrol : master
2023-02-02 18:53:52,968 (DEBUG) ebcli.core.fileoperations : Project root found at: /Users/username/Documents/GitHub/server
2023-02-02 18:53:52,969 (DEBUG) ebcli.core.fileoperations : Project root found at: /Users/username/Documents/GitHub/server
2023-02-02 18:53:52,970 (DEBUG) ebcli.core.fileoperations : Project root found at: /Users/username/Documents/GitHub/server
2023-02-02 18:53:52,971 (DEBUG) ebcli.objects.sourcecontrol : Getting current branch name by performing `git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD`
2023-02-02 18:53:52,977 (DEBUG) ebcli.objects.sourcecontrol : master
2023-02-02 18:53:52,977 (DEBUG) ebcli.core.fileoperations : Project root found at: /Users/username/Documents/GitHub/server
2023-02-02 18:53:52,978 (DEBUG) ebcli.core.fileoperations : Project root found at: /Users/username/Documents/GitHub/server
2023-02-02 18:53:52,979 (DEBUG) ebcli.core.fileoperations : Project root found at: /Users/username/Documents/GitHub/server
2023-02-02 18:53:52,980 (DEBUG) ebcli.core.fileoperations : Project root found at: /Users/username/Documents/GitHub/server
2023-02-02 18:53:52,981 (DEBUG) ebcli.lib.utils : docker --version
2023-02-02 18:53:53,111 (DEBUG) ebcli.lib.utils : Docker version 20.10.22, build 3a2c30b

2023-02-02 18:53:53,123 (DEBUG) ebcli.core.fileoperations : Project root found at: /Users/username/Documents/GitHub/server
2023-02-02 18:53:53,125 (DEBUG) ebcli.objects.sourcecontrol : Getting current branch name by performing `git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD`
2023-02-02 18:53:53,132 (DEBUG) ebcli.objects.sourcecontrol : master
2023-02-02 18:53:53,132 (DEBUG) ebcli.core.fileoperations : Project root found at: /Users/username/Documents/GitHub/server
2023-02-02 18:53:53,133 (DEBUG) ebcli.core.fileoperations : Project root found at: /Users/username/Documents/GitHub/server
2023-02-02 18:53:53,134 (DEBUG) ebcli.lib.elasticbeanstalk : Inside list_platform_branches api wrapper
2023-02-02 18:53:53,134 (DEBUG) ebcli.lib.aws : Creating new Botocore Session
2023-02-02 18:53:53,134 (DEBUG) ebcli.lib.aws : Botocore version: 1.23.54
2023-02-02 18:53:53,138 (DEBUG) ebcli.lib.aws : Creating new Botocore Client for elasticbeanstalk
2023-02-02 18:53:53,372 (DEBUG) ebcli.lib.aws : Successfully created session for elasticbeanstalk
2023-02-02 18:53:53,372 (DEBUG) ebcli.lib.aws : Making api call: (elasticbeanstalk, list_platform_branches) to region: us-east-2 with args:{'Filters': [{'Attribute': 'BranchName', 'Operator': '=', 'Values': ['Node.js 16']}]}
2023-02-02 18:53:54,561 (DEBUG) ebcli.lib.aws : API call finished, status = 200
2023-02-02 18:53:54,561 (DEBUG) ebcli.lib.aws : Response: {'PlatformBranchSummaryList': [], 'ResponseMetadata': {'RequestId': 'dab8c0e2-24ee-4091-aed3-714fa90425ae', 'HTTPStatusCode': 200, 'date': 'Fri, 03 Feb 2023 04:53:53 GMT', 'RetryAttempts': 0}}
2023-02-02 18:53:54,561 (DEBUG) ebcli.lib.elasticbeanstalk : Inside get_available_solution_stacks api wrapper
2023-02-02 18:53:54,561 (DEBUG) ebcli.lib.aws : Making api call: (elasticbeanstalk, list_available_solution_stacks) to region: us-east-2 with args:{}
2023-02-02 18:53:55,145 (DEBUG) ebcli.lib.aws : API call finished, status = 200
2023-02-02 18:53:55,146 (DEBUG) ebcli.lib.aws : Response: {'SolutionStacks': ['64bit Amazon Linux 2018.03 v2.12.0 running Ruby 2.3 (Puma)', '64bit Amazon Linux 2018.03 v2.12.0 running Ruby 2.2 (Puma)', '64bit Amazon Linux 2018.03 v2.12.0 running Ruby 2.1 (Puma)', '64bit Amazon Linux 2018.03 v2.12.0 running Ruby 2.0 (Puma)', '64bit Amazon Linux 2018.03 v2.12.0 running Ruby 2.3 (Passenger Standalone)', '64bit Amazon Linux 2018.03 v2.12.0 running Ruby 2.2 (Passenger Standalone)', '64bit Amazon Linux 2018.03 v2.12.0 running Ruby 2.1 (Passenger Standalone)', '64bit Amazon Linux 2018.03 v2.12.0 running Ruby 2.0 (Passenger Standalone)', '64bit Amazon Linux 2018.03 v2.12.0 running Ruby 1.9.3', '64bit Debian jessie v2.16.0 running Go 1.4 (Preconfigured - Docker)', '64bit Debian jessie v2.16.0 running Go 1.3 (Preconfigured - Docker)', '64bit Amazon Linux 2018.03 v3.4.0 running Tomcat 8 Java 8', '64bit Amazon Linux 2018.03 v3.4.0 running Tomcat 7 Java 6', '64bit Debian jessie v2.16.0 running Python 3.4 (Preconfigured - Docker)', '64bit Amazon Linux 2018.03 v2.9.11 running PHP 5.4', '64bit Amazon Linux 2018.03 v2.9.11 running PHP 5.5', '64bit Amazon Linux 2018.03 v2.9.11 running PHP 5.6', '64bit Amazon Linux 2018.03 v2.9.11 running PHP 7.0', '64bit Amazon Linux 2018.03 v2.9.11 running PHP 7.1', '64bit Amazon Linux 2018.03 v2.6.33 running Packer 1.0.3', '64bit Amazon Linux 2018.03 v2.9.15 running Python 3.4', '64bit Amazon Linux 2018.03 v2.9.15 running Python', '64bit Amazon Linux 2018.03 v2.9.15 running Python 2.7', '64bit Amazon Linux 2 v3.4.4 running Corretto 17', '64bit Amazon Linux 2 v3.4.4 running Corretto 11', '64bit Amazon Linux 2 v3.4.4 running Corretto 8', '64bit Amazon Linux 2 v2.5.0 running .NET Core', '64bit Amazon Linux 2 v3.4.4 running Python 3.8', '64bit Amazon Linux 2 v3.4.4 running Python 3.7', '64bit Amazon Linux 2 v5.6.4 running Node.js 16', '64bit Amazon Linux 2 v5.6.4 running Node.js 14', '64bit Amazon Linux 2 v3.2.4 running ECS', '64bit Amazon Linux 2 v3.5.4 running PHP 8.1', '64bit Amazon Linux 2 v3.5.4 running PHP 8.0', '64bit Amazon Linux 2 v3.5.4 running PHP 7.4', '64bit Amazon Linux 2 v3.5.4 running Docker', '64bit Amazon Linux 2 v3.6.3 running Ruby 3.0', '64bit Amazon Linux 2 v3.6.3 running Ruby 2.7', '64bit Amazon Linux 2 v3.6.4 running Go 1', '64bit Amazon Linux 2 v4.3.4 running Tomcat 8.5 Corretto 11', '64bit Amazon Linux 2 v4.3.4 running Tomcat 8.5 Corretto 8', '64bit Windows Server Core 2019 v2.11.0 running IIS 10.0', '64bit Windows Server 2019 v2.11.0 running IIS 10.0', '64bit Windows Server Core 2016 v2.11.0 running IIS 10.0', '64bit Windows Server 2016 v2.11.0 running IIS 10.0', '64bit Windows Server Core 2012 R2 v2.11.0 running IIS 8.5', '64bit Windows Server 2012 R2 v2.11.0 running IIS 8.5'], 'SolutionStackDetails': [{'SolutionStackName': '64bit Amazon Linux 2018.03 v2.12.0 running Ruby 2.3 (Puma)', 'PermittedFileTypes': ['zip']}, {'SolutionStackName': '64bit Amazon Linux 2018.03 v2.12.0 running Ruby 2.2 (Puma)', 'PermittedFileTypes': ['zip']}, {'SolutionStackName': '64bit Amazon Linux 2018.03 v2.12.0 running Ruby 2.1 (Puma)', 'PermittedFileTypes': ['zip']}, {'SolutionStackName': '64bit Amazon Linux 2018.03 v2.12.0 running Ruby 2.0 (Puma)', 'PermittedFileTypes': ['zip']}, {'SolutionStackName': '64bit Amazon Linux 2018.03 v2.12.0 running Ruby 2.3 (Passenger Standalone)', 'PermittedFileTypes': ['zip']}, {'SolutionStackName': '64bit Amazon Linux 2018.03 v2.12.0 running Ruby 2.2 (Passenger Standalone)', 'PermittedFileTypes': ['zip']}, {'SolutionStackName': '64bit Amazon Linux 2018.03 v2.12.0 running Ruby 2.1 (Passenger Standalone)', 'PermittedFileTypes': ['zip']}, {'SolutionStackName': '64bit Amazon Linux 2018.03 v2.12.0 running Ruby 2.0 (Passenger Standalone)', 'PermittedFileTypes': ['zip']}, {'SolutionStackName': '64bit Amazon Linux 2018.03 v2.12.0 running Ruby 1.9.3', 'PermittedFileTypes': ['zip']}, {'SolutionStackName': '64bit Debian jessie v2.16.0 running Go 1.4 (Preconfigured - Docker)', 'PermittedFileTypes': ['zip']}, {'SolutionStackName': '64bit Debian jessie v2.16.0 running Go 1.3 (Preconfigured - Docker)', 'PermittedFileTypes': ['zip']}, {'SolutionStackName': '64bit Amazon Linux 2018.03 v3.4.0 running Tomcat 8 Java 8', 'PermittedFileTypes': ['war', 'zip']}, {'SolutionStackName': '64bit Amazon Linux 2018.03 v3.4.0 running Tomcat 7 Java 6', 'PermittedFileTypes': ['war', 'zip']}, {'SolutionStackName': '64bit Debian jessie v2.16.0 running Python 3.4 (Preconfigured - Docker)', 'PermittedFileTypes': ['zip']}, {'SolutionStackName': '64bit Amazon Linux 2018.03 v2.9.11 running PHP 5.4', 'PermittedFileTypes': ['zip']}, {'SolutionStackName': '64bit Amazon Linux 2018.03 v2.9.11 running PHP 5.5', 'PermittedFileTypes': ['zip']}, {'SolutionStackName': '64bit Amazon Linux 2018.03 v2.9.11 running PHP 5.6', 'PermittedFileTypes': ['zip']}, {'SolutionStackName': '64bit Amazon Linux 2018.03 v2.9.11 running PHP 7.0', 'PermittedFileTypes': ['zip']}, {'SolutionStackName': '64bit Amazon Linux 2018.03 v2.9.11 running PHP 7.1', 'PermittedFileTypes': ['zip']}, {'SolutionStackName': '64bit Amazon Linux 2018.03 v2.6.33 running Packer 1.0.3', 'PermittedFileTypes': []}, {'SolutionStackName': '64bit Amazon Linux 2018.03 v2.9.15 running Python 3.4', 'PermittedFileTypes': ['zip']}, {'SolutionStackName': '64bit Amazon Linux 2018.03 v2.9.15 running Python', 'PermittedFileTypes': ['zip']}, {'SolutionStackName': '64bit Amazon Linux 2018.03 v2.9.15 running Python 2.7', 'PermittedFileTypes': ['zip']}, {'SolutionStackName': '64bit Amazon Linux 2 v3.4.4 running Corretto 17', 'PermittedFileTypes': ['jar', 'zip']}, {'SolutionStackName': '64bit Amazon Linux 2 v3.4.4 running Corretto 11', 'PermittedFileTypes': ['jar', 'zip']}, {'SolutionStackName': '64bit Amazon Linux 2 v3.4.4 running Corretto 8', 'PermittedFileTypes': ['jar', 'zip']}, {'SolutionStackName': '64bit Amazon Linux 2 v2.5.0 running .NET Core', 'PermittedFileTypes': ['zip']}, {'SolutionStackName': '64bit Amazon Linux 2 v3.4.4 running Python 3.8', 'PermittedFileTypes': ['zip']}, {'SolutionStackName': '64bit Amazon Linux 2 v3.4.4 running Python 3.7', 'PermittedFileTypes': ['zip']}, {'SolutionStackName': '64bit Amazon Linux 2 v5.6.4 running Node.js 16', 'PermittedFileTypes': ['zip']}, {'SolutionStackName': '64bit Amazon Linux 2 v5.6.4 running Node.js 14', 'PermittedFileTypes': ['zip']}, {'SolutionStackName': '64bit Amazon Linux 2 v3.2.4 running ECS', 'PermittedFileTypes': []}, {'SolutionStackName': '64bit Amazon Linux 2 v3.5.4 running PHP 8.1', 'PermittedFileTypes': ['zip']}, {'SolutionStackName': '64bit Amazon Linux 2 v3.5.4 running PHP 8.0', 'PermittedFileTypes': ['zip']}, {'SolutionStackName': '64bit Amazon Linux 2 v3.5.4 running PHP 7.4', 'PermittedFileTypes': ['zip']}, {'SolutionStackName': '64bit Amazon Linux 2 v3.5.4 running Docker', 'PermittedFileTypes': []}, {'SolutionStackName': '64bit Amazon Linux 2 v3.6.3 running Ruby 3.0', 'PermittedFileTypes': ['zip']}, {'SolutionStackName': '64bit Amazon Linux 2 v3.6.3 running Ruby 2.7', 'PermittedFileTypes': ['zip']}, {'SolutionStackName': '64bit Amazon Linux 2 v3.6.4 running Go 1', 'PermittedFileTypes': ['zip']}, {'SolutionStackName': '64bit Amazon Linux 2 v4.3.4 running Tomcat 8.5 Corretto 11', 'PermittedFileTypes': ['war', 'zip']}, {'SolutionStackName': '64bit Amazon Linux 2 v4.3.4 running Tomcat 8.5 Corretto 8', 'PermittedFileTypes': ['war', 'zip']}, {'SolutionStackName': '64bit Windows Server Core 2019 v2.11.0 running IIS 10.0', 'PermittedFileTypes': ['zip']}, {'SolutionStackName': '64bit Windows Server 2019 v2.11.0 running IIS 10.0', 'PermittedFileTypes': ['zip']}, {'SolutionStackName': '64bit Windows Server Core 2016 v2.11.0 running IIS 10.0', 'PermittedFileTypes': ['zip']}, {'SolutionStackName': '64bit Windows Server 2016 v2.11.0 running IIS 10.0', 'PermittedFileTypes': ['zip']}, {'SolutionStackName': '64bit Windows Server Core 2012 R2 v2.11.0 running IIS 8.5', 'PermittedFileTypes': ['zip']}, {'SolutionStackName': '64bit Windows Server 2012 R2 v2.11.0 running IIS 8.5', 'PermittedFileTypes': ['zip']}], 'ResponseMetadata': {'RequestId': 'a95879bd-2a54-4e7a-b70b-031ded370893', 'HTTPStatusCode': 200, 'date': 'Fri, 03 Feb 2023 04:53:53 GMT', 'RetryAttempts': 0}}
2023-02-02 18:53:55,156 (DEBUG) ebcli.lib.elasticbeanstalk : Solution Stack result size = 47
2023-02-02 18:53:55,165 (INFO) eb : Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/username/.ebcli-virtual-env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ebcli/core/ebrun.py", line 62, in run_app
    app.run()
  File "/Users/username/.ebcli-virtual-env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/cement/core/foundation.py", line 797, in run
    return_val = self.controller._dispatch()
  File "/Users/username/.ebcli-virtual-env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/cement/core/controller.py", line 472, in _dispatch
    return func()
  File "/Users/username/.ebcli-virtual-env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/cement/core/controller.py", line 472, in _dispatch
    return func()
  File "/Users/username/.ebcli-virtual-env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/cement/core/controller.py", line 478, in _dispatch
    return func()
  File "/Users/username/.ebcli-virtual-env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ebcli/core/abstractcontroller.py", line 92, in default
    self.do_command()
  File "/Users/username/.ebcli-virtual-env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ebcli/controllers/local.py", line 62, in do_command
    cnt = factory.make_container(self.app.pargs.envvars,
  File "/Users/username/.ebcli-virtual-env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ebcli/containers/factory.py", line 76, in make_container
    raise NotSupportedError(strings['local.unsupported'])
ebcli.objects.exceptions.NotSupportedError: You can use "eb local" only with preconfigured, generic and multicontainer Docker platforms.
```